# any trick to unpack a variadic macro?

Tags: c++, variadic-macros

Any trick to unpack a variadic macro? For example,

`#define READ(...)` means read the arguments one by one

`READ(a, b, c)` will be unpacked to `read(a); read(b); read(c)`

Comment: Why are you using a macro in the first place? Why not variadic templates arguments where this can be done quite easily?

Comment: Agreed. This is trivial with a variadic template. If macros are absolutely necessary, something like `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`.

Comment: Here read(a) is not a statement. It is a macro to define a function or class.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with the "paired sliding args" macro technique as described here:
https://codecraft.co/2014/11/25/variadic-macros-tricks

```
#define _EXPAND(args) args
#define READ1(a) read(a);
#define READ2(a,b) read(a); read(b);
#define READ3(a,b,c) read(a); read(b); read(c);
#define GETREAD(_1,_2,_3, READN,...) READN
#define READ(...) _EXPAND(GETREAD(__VA_ARGS__, READ3, READ2, READ1)(__VA_ARGS__))
```

The `_EXPAND(args)` is only needed in MSVC.